# 3D glasses and reflection/polarisation

Tags: optics, reflection, polarization

[image: First picture]
[image: Second picture]

Hi all,
Tonight I'm going to see a 3D film so I thought I'd check whether I had any old 3D glasses around the house. Found a pair of "RealD" glasses.

Anyhow, I assume that the glasses use some kind of polarisation to work. So I played around with looking through them in the bathroom mirror.

The first picture shows me holding the glasses facing towards the mirror, and looking through one of the lenses at the reflection in the mirror. One of the reflected lenses looks black and the other looks transparent. Cool! Polarisation in action.

However, the right-hand picture shows me holding the glasses facing away from the mirror - and in that picture, when I look through one of the lenses at the reflection, both reflected lenses appear transparent.

What on earth is going on? Dumbed-down explanation suitable for a mere mathematician, please :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing computer screen through 3D glasses, why the asymmetry?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/182600/)